# how to adjust text according to screen width in Android

Tags: android, textview

I am new at Android Development. I am working on a project in which I have to show some questions and answers and for answers I don't want to implement horizontal scrolling. I want that answer's text should adjust itself according to screen width and the user is only left with vertical scrolling. How to implement this scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

calculate font size and how many characters can be occupied in one line according to particular screen size.

Comment: this can not be the answer @AnkitAora